# Provide own rotation animation when device is rotated

Tags: android

I want to handle button rotation when device is rotated. I've tried to handle `onConfigurationChanged`, but, by default, button is rotated with screen.

How can I achieve this?

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ru.study"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".AuthActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that I choose a wrong way to do this. To provide own animation (or other events) on device rotation, it's better to use [Sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the configChanges attribute for your activity in the manifest file.
    `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

thus your activity won't be recreated upon rotating the device, but instead you need to handle the configuration change in the `onConfigurationChanged` method of your activity.